# Recursively search directories for a filename, stop descending if found

Tags: bash, find, directory-structure

I have a directory-tree which contains files with the same name, e.g.:

```bsh
a/file
a/...
a/b/file
x/a/file
x/a/...
x/b/file
```

I'm trying to use `find` (with `-exec` and `-prune`) to get all paths where `file` occurs first when recursively searching the tree. My example would return:

```
a/file
x/a/file
x/b/file
```

It does not return `a/b/file` because a file called `file` is already in `a/`.

How can I achieve that with Bash?

Comment: Why is `x/b/file` returned?  Are you assuming an ordered search (sorted names)? `find` does not sort directories or the contents of directories.

Comment: maybe you could use the -mindepth -maxdepth parameters and put find into a while loop. not too efficient tho. other tought is you call a script with -exec which prints the filename then kill the find

Comment: Edit for my last comment: kill the find isn't good, because the first file found not necessary on the highest level

Comment: @Kusalananda x/b/file is independent of x/a/file and has thus to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
   f="$1"/file
   [ -e "$f" ] && { printf "%s\n" "$f"; true; }
' find-sh {} \; -prune
```

Instead of finding files I find directories and test the existence of `file` in each directory. If `file` exists, the path to it is printed and `-prune` activated for the directory.

Notes:

- `true` is there to make sure `-prune` does its job even if `printf` fails for whatever reason.
- In this solution `find` never processes any `file`, it processes directories. If you want to do something with `file`, you can do it from within the inner shell, using `$f`.

  Example: if I used `… -prune -print`, the tool would print the relevant directory pathname, not the file. To print the path to `file` I used `printf` from within the inner shell.

Comment: It works, but I don't understand how. `-prune` makes it stop at the first level of the tree. Is it the `true` in the exec-block?

Comment: @PatrickB. `-exec … \;` is also a test. Its result depends on the exit status of the command. In this case the command is `sh`. Its exit status is the exit status of the last command invoked in the shell code. If `[` yields non-zero exit status then it's "false" from `[`; if `[` yields zero then it's "true" from `true` (without `true` it would most likely be "true" from `printf`, but in some circumstances it may be "false" from `printf`, so I added `true`). If `-exec` as a test fails then `-prune` is not evaluated.

Comment: Hi Kamil: can you explain the `find-sh`  please. I can't find a ref to it anywhere.

Comment: @Cbhihe See `man 1 bash` where it describes `-c`. `find-sh` becomes `$0` "used in warning and error messages". The POSIX shell (`sh`) also works this way. Therefore names like `find-bash-1`, `find-sh-2` or `special-shell` may be useful: when you get an error with such name, you immediately can tell which "inner" shell generated it.

Comment: @Cbhihe Instead of `… find-sh {} \;` I could use `… {} \;`. Then in the context of the inner shell I would need to use `$0` (instead of `$1`) to refer to what `{}` was substituted with (by `find`). It would work. But in case of any warning or error from the inner shell I would see it with some "random" file in it. This would be very confusing. Compare `find /dev -exec sh -c 'invalid-code-foo' {} \;` to `find /dev -exec sh -c 'invalid-code-foo' find-sh {} \;`.

Comment: @Cbhihe About `find-sh`: I created a separate [question on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690) and answered it decently.